# How to secure secrets in html file hosted on Github pages?

Tags: html, github, environment-variables, github-pages

I am creating a weather app in HTML and host it on GitHub pages.
I am using a secret key to fetch the city's weather details.

I don't want to public the secret key.

How can I secure the secret key in HTML application?

Comment: Anything commited in source control becomes inherently public. So, don't commit it into source control, leave a placeholder and only fill it in production.

Answer (score 1):

read the github docs:

https://docs.github.com/en/github/developing-online-with-codespaces/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-codespaces#about-encrypted-secrets-for-codespaces

and the second link has the video to it as well with sets of instructions

https://www.theserverside.com/blog/Coffee-Talk-Java-News-Stories-and-Opinions/GitHub-Actions-Secrets-Example-Token-Tutorial

Comment: This just directs the person to URLs, without quoting them, which should be avoided. Also, this does not really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to do this, but an alternative is to use a tool like [JavaScript Obfuscator Tool](https://obfuscator.io/) to make it harder to find the secret. However, this is not perfect.